# AWK is inserting in the beginning instead of appending, only with specific input

Tags: awk

I wrote a simple awk one liner to append a string before and after each each line of a given file:

```
awk '{print "--> " $0 " <--"}' filename
```

Now I have a test file containing these lines:

```
test
test2
test3
```

The result is as expected:

```
--> test <--
--> test2 <--
--> test3 <--
```

However, these are my real lines I need to process:

```
"\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b"
"\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c"
"\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c"
```

Processing those with the very same one liner will not work, it will instead only insert the rightmost arrow in front of the line.

```
 <--"\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x20\x21\x22\x23\x24\x25\x26\x27\x28\x29\x2a\x2b\x2c\x2d\x2e\x2f\x30\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x3a\x3b"
 <--"\x3c\x3d\x3e\x3f\x40\x41\x42\x43\x44\x45\x46\x47\x48\x49\x4a\x4b\x4c\x4d\x4f\x50\x51\x52\x53\x54\x55\x56\x57\x58\x59\x5a\x5b\x5c"
 <--"\x5d\x5e\x5f\x60\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x67\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x77\x78\x79\x7a\x7b\x7c"
```

Why is this happening and how can I work around it?

Comment: You got CRLF line endings in the file

Comment: I concur with @Fravadona.  Moreover you may not be seeing the whole output due to overlap on the console.

Comment: Your awk procedure works fine on the same data on my system (GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0, on raspberry pi  400).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your input file contains dos/windows line endings (`\r\n`); try ...

```
head -2 filename | od -c
```

... and you should see each line ending with `\r \n`.

Run `dos2unix filename` to permanently remove the `\r` characters from the file.

Alternatively you can have `awk` strip the `\r`, eg:

```
awk '{sub(/\r/,""); print "--> " $0 " <--"}' filename
```

Comment: Nit-pick - `\r` can occur and isn't "special" in a text file unless it's at the end of a line so `sub(/\r/,"")` should really be `sub(/\r$/,"")` to avoid removing the first `\r` in the line and leaving the trailing one.